# Sidebar widget not displaying after simple code update. 

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I registered a sidebar widget, then modified the registration which included changing the registered name of the widget. Now the widget does not show at all. Below are the steps I took.

1. I registered a sidebar widget in my functions.php file.

   ```
   if (function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
       register_sidebar( array('name' => 'Right Sidebar') );
   }
   ```
2. In my template page, I then dropped in the appropriate calls for the widget, like so...

   ```
   <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
       ...some html...
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
3. Then after doing some further reading in the codex **(i'm a noob)**, I decided to do a bit more clean-up and test out all the parameters of register_sidebar(), so...
4. In functions.php, I CHANGED the call from the above to this (which is taken directly from **[the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar#Example)**):

   ```
   if (function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
       register_sidebar(array(
         'name' => 'RightSideBar',
         'id' => 'right-sidebar',
         'description' => 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.',
         'before_title' => '<h1>',
         'after_title' => '</h1>'
       ));
   }
   ```
5. I then went to *Admin > Appearance* and, sure enough the new and improved sidebar widget was showing, but was empty. So I added a few widgets.
6. I then tested the page in the browser: **No Widgets.** Just the default mark-up I added.
7. I checked the code. Looks right to my *noob* eyes.
8. So I decided to back out of the changes and reverted to the previous code (see step 1).
9. To my amazement, in the admin all the previous settings **were still there** (Sidebar, widgets and all)! Plus the widgets showed right up on the page.
10. Then I re-added the new code (see #4) and, same thing: All the widgets I added to the **new and improved** version also were saved (somewhere in the db, for some reason beyond my pay grade) and also showed (in the admin section, but **NOT** on the page).
11. This leads to the question: **Do I need to (somehow) deregister the sidebar widget?** ( since the DB is apparently storing these values *"somewhere"*).
12. A bit more digging pulled up this little function: **[unregister_sidebar( $id )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar#Example)**;
13. Do I really need to use this? My original goal was to completely rename and update the sidebar.

So... I need a clue :D

Thanks,

sleeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you don't need the others settings from register_sidebar, that's fine.
2. That's not fine. :) 
   To render your sidebar you need to call

   ```
    dynamic_sidebar($index);
   ```

   In your case it would be:

   ```
    dynamic_sidebar('Right Sidebar');
   ```

   see the codex page for dynamic sidebar
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

   Your current code says (short version): If there is no sidebar, then do my custom code.
   Look at the examples from the linked codex page.
3. skipped
4. If you need those settings for a sidebar, use them, but notice, and that's what happend on your sidebar/widget configuration page when your old sidebar disappeared.

If you register a sidebar with an ID, WordPress looks in the database for this ID, if you just register a sidebar with a name, WordPress will look for the name.

Your ID was different from the original name, and there was no entry for a sidebar with this id. 
The name gets ignored, when an ID is set.

Hope that makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was "spot on"! I modified code to use your #2 (also wrapped in an `if ( function exists ( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) ) {...`) and all is well. Also reviewed the [codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar#Examples) in #2 and I understand everything **BUT** the example used. Are they saying to declare **TWO** UL's: one for not dynamic and one for dynamic?

Comment: p.s. Looking at [sidebar.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-content/themes/twentyten/sidebar.php) really cleared things up.

Comment: using <ul> is kind of "best practice" since the default settings for 'before_widget' and 'after_widget' are <li> resp. </li>. you can overwrite this when defining your sidebar if you don't want to wrap your widgets inside a <ul>. more a question about semantics actually.

Comment: Got it. I'm sticking with the best practices for now. :D